# Paysafe POSTMAN 404 for cardpayments

Tags: netbanx-api, paysafe

I am unable to run a proper transaction. I am not coding right away. I wanted to test it with POSTMAN first but I seem to be running in to problems.

I am using the following endpoint

https://api.test.paysafe.com/cardpayments/v1/accounts/89994061

Sample Request (Code)

```
> {
>     "merchantRefNum": "ORDER_ID:12312",
>     "amount": 10098,
>     "settleWithAuth": true,
>     "card": {
>         "cardNum": "4111111111111111",
>         "cardExpiry": {
>             "month": 2,
>             "year": 2017
>         },
>       "cvv":111
>     },
>     "billingDetails": {
>         "zip": "M5H 2N2"
>     } }
```

Sample Response (Code)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Draft//EN">
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <TITLE>Error 404--Not Found</TITLE>
    </HEAD>
    <BODY bgcolor="white">
        <FONT FACE=Helvetica>
            <BR CLEAR=all>
            <TABLE border=0 cellspacing=5>
                <TR>
                    <TD>
                        <BR CLEAR=all>
                        <FONT FACE="Helvetica" COLOR="black" SIZE="3">
                            <H2>Error 404--Not Found</H2>
                        </FONT>
                    </TD>
                </TR>
            </TABLE>
            <TABLE border=0 width=100% cellpadding=10>
                <TR>
                    <TD VALIGN=top WIDTH=100% BGCOLOR=white>
                        <FONT FACE="Courier New">
                            <FONT FACE="Helvetica" SIZE="3">
                                <H3>From RFC 2068 
                                    <i>Hypertext Transfer Protocol -- HTTP/1.1</i>:
                                </H3>
                            </FONT>
                            <FONT FACE="Helvetica" SIZE="3">
                                <H4>10.4.5 404 Not Found</H4>
                            </FONT>
                            <P>
                                <FONT FACE="Courier New">The server has not found anything matching the Request-URI. No indication is given of whether the condition is temporary or permanent.
                                </p>
                                <p>If the server does not wish to make this information available to the client, the status code 403 (Forbidden) can be used instead. The 410 (Gone) status code SHOULD be used if the server knows, through some internally configurable mechanism, that an old resource is permanently unavailable and has no forwarding address.
                                </FONT>
                            </P>
                        </FONT>
                    </TD>
                </TR>
            </TABLE>
        </BODY>
    </HTML>
```

Seems the endpoint is incorrect. I received this from your developer center. What is incorrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would seem that your endpoints are missing some parameters. What you have is the basic format of the Card Payments API. If you wish to process an actual payment, you need to add certain parameters at the end. Please see example below.

**Authorizations**

```
https://api.test.netbanx.com/cardpayments/v1/accounts/89994061/auths
```

**Settlements**

```
https://api.test.netbanx.com/cardpayments/v1/accounts/89994061/settlements
```

There are many more but you can find them on the Paysafe Developer Center.